# Custom listview checkbox and edit box loss data when scroll down

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

Hello every one I am new to android I have custom `Listview` with `editText` and `checkbox` when I check the box and enter data in `editText` and scroll the `listView` and return back to that box its change its state to previous state means unchecked and `editText` box data lost public

```
public View getView(final int position, View arg1, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (arg1 == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        arg1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stocklistcustom, viewGroup, false);
        holder.checkbox1 = (CheckBox) arg1.findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);
        holder.Des = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.description);
        holder.stockid = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.stockid);
        holder.done = (EditText) arg1.findViewById(R.id.quantity);

        holder.stockid.setText(listItem.get(position));
        holder.Des.setText(listAddress.get(position));
        holder.done.setText(quantity.get(position));

        holder.checkbox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                int i = 0;
                if (holder.checkbox1.isChecked()) {

                    String id, qu, des, stc;
                    id = idlist.get(position);
                    qu = quantity.get(position);
                    des = listAddress.get(position);
                    stc = listItem.get(position);

                    ItemID_list.add(i, id);
                    StockCode_list.add(i, stc);
                    Description_list.add(des);
                    Quantity_list.add(i, holder.done.getText().toString());


                } else {

                    ItemID_list.remove(i);
                    StockCode_list.remove(i);
                    Description_list.remove(i);
                    Quantity_list.remove(i);
                    i--;
                }
            }
        });




        arg1.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) arg1.getTag();
    }



    //date.setText(dates);



    return arg1;
}

static class ViewHolder{
    CheckBox checkbox1;
    TextView Des;
     TextView stockid;
    EditText done;


}
```

this is my getview function if any body can solve this problem please

Comment: use RicycleView With ViewHolder in Android

Comment: thanks for your feedback can you give me any link where i can solve my this issue i searched alot bot failled

Comment: first u user RicycleView instead of ListView

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar, it won't solve a problem. The problem is that you have to save the values once they are changed somewhere

Comment: check this link http://burnignorance.com/android-apps-development/keeping-the-data-in-listview-with-interactive-items-while-scrolling-in-android/

Comment: if u want to implement the new Recycler view instead of list view then refer this http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Comment: sir please show me some way to do this

Comment: please check this one http://burnignorance.com/android-apps-development/keeping-the-data-in-listview-with-interactive-items-while-scrolling-in-android/ , you can solve ur issue using the same recycler view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is, you are not saving the view that is created by listview upon scrolling. So, first understand how listview works, it always creates a new instance from the convertView when it is being scrolled. So, I suggest you use the ViewHolder pattern for the listview and setTag() function to set the information and retrieve from it through getTag() upon scrolling back.

```
    static class ViewHolder{
    CheckBox checkbox1;
    TextView Des;
    final TextView stockid;
    final EditText done;
    }
```

And change the code in getView as follows:

```
View getView(final int position, View arg1, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    if(arg1 == null){
        arg1 = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.stocklistcustom, viewGroup, false);
//Now set all your views using arg1
//do all your stuff
arg1.setTag(holder);
    }else{
    holder = (ViewHolder) arg1.getTag();
}

return arg1;
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion sir its works for me but when i select a checkbox its check another checkbox below to . .

Comment: That is because the convertView is reinitializing the view whenever a scroll event is occured. This is inevitable in listView. 
So, instead if you have less data go with ScrollView or else use RecyclerView with ViewHolder to achieve this.

Comment: If you are familiar with the SQLiteDatabase you can use that to store each click of the checkbox in a table and retrieve it based on your item position upon scrolling.

Comment: i will try this . . now i am trying to solve this with RecyclerView with ViewHolder

Answer (score 0):

Create boolean 'isChecked' and update your code

```
checkbox1.setChecked(isChecked);
checkbox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

  @Override
  public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    this.isChecked = isChecked;
    //Follow as you code......................
  }
});
```

Comment: @Media This is hardly constructive criticism. Please explain *why* you think so, or don't leave a comment at all.

Comment: In getView Method, you are inflating new view always for every item and its check box is also have new instance.

Comment: sorry if i use bad words but i used this code its not working . .